# node.js http-proxy proxy based on url

Tags: node.js, proxy, http-proxy

I would like to create a proxy based on URL, such that you can go to: blah.com:8000/tolley-ltm and it proxies that request to my local workstation such as tolley.internal.blah.com based on the URL. So I could also do blah.com:8000/someguy-ltm and it goes to some guy's workstation at someguy-ltm.internal.blah.com. The end user will only ever see blah.com:8000/tolley-ltm

I have this sort of working, but not 100% and I would like your help! Here is the current code:

```
var fulltld ="internal.blah.com";
var proxyServer = httpProxy.createProxy();

var options = {
  '/tolley-ltm': 'tolley-ltm',
  '/someguy-ltm': 'someguy-ltm'
}

require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {

  var dest = req.url;
  req.url = '/';

  fail = function(err){  
    console.log("Something bad happened: " + err);
  }

  proxyServer.web(req, res, {
    target: {
        host: options[dest] + '.' + fulltld,
        port: 6109
    }
  },fail);
}).listen(8000);
```

So what happens currently is I go to blah.com:8000/tolley-ltm in my browser and it successfully goes to tolley.internal.blah.com:6109, however when I navigate since I changed the req.url to / instead of tolley-ltm every subsequent actions then goes to blah.com:8000/ instead of blah.com:8000/tolley-ltm and this causes the proxy to stop working.

Sidenote: If I don't change the req.url to '/' it ends up proxying to tolley.internal.blah.com:6109/tolley-ltm instead of just tolley.internal.blah.com:6109/

Is there a way I can keep the url to the end user looking like blah.com/8000/tolley-ltm and have all actions call back to blah.com/8000-ltm, such as if I clicked a link to go to /products, it would take me to blah.com/8000/tolley-ltm/products instead of blah.com/8000/products